# Stacking .rds files in R

Tags: r, raster

I have multiple .rds that I want to stack and save as one .rds file. They all have the same resolution. I used this function to read my files and it worked.

```
SeaTurtles_IUCNdist <- list.files(path="RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/",
                                  pattern = "rds$", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map_dfr(readRDS)

> class(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist)
[1] "sf"         "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

However, when I used the function stack()

```
SeaTurtles_stack <- raster::stack(paste0("RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/", SeaTurtles_IUCNdist))
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
> SeaTurtles_stack <- raster::stack(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist,"RDS_Species/RasterStacks/AllSeaTurtles_IUCNdist.rds")
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `RDS_Species/RasterStacks/AllSeaTurtles_IUCNdist.rds` doesn't exist.
```

I don't understand the error... How can I proceed to stack my files and save them?

Comment: You should probably stack the `SeaTurtles_IUCNdist` list, not the *filenames*.

Comment: `raster::stack()`'s second argument is `bands` which is supposed to be an integer (number) of the bands/layers to use. Instead of an integer you are supplying a character/file path. Try `raster::stack(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist)`, it should lead to the result you are looking for.

Comment: > raster::stack(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist)
Error in data.frame(values = unlist(unname(x)), ind, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2759475, 367930
In addition: Warning message:
In stack.data.frame(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist) :
  non-vector columns will be ignored
I got this error when trying that

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have these rds files. I do not know what they contain, but I do know that raster::stack cannot read them.

```
ff <- list.files(path="RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/", pattern = "rds$", full.names = TRUE)
```

What may work is to read them and then use `stack` -- under the assumption that the `rds` file contain valid `RasterLayer`s ("valud is key here. It is generally not safe to save Raster* objects to "rds")

```
library(raster)
x <- lapply(ff, readRDS)
s <- stack(x)
```

Comment: Hi, when using the lapply() function, I got this error:
> x <- lapply(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist, readRDS)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : bad 'file' argument

Comment: Why do you do that? I show `x <- lapply(ff, readRDS)`

Comment: Hi, it also did not work I got this message:

`> SeaTurtles_IUCNdist <- list.files(path="RDS_Species/SeaTurtles/",
+                                   pattern = "rds$", full.names = TRUE) 
>   x <- lapply(SeaTurtles_IUCNdist, readRDS)
>   s <- stack(x)
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  Arguments should be Raster* objects or filenames` @Robert Hijmans

Comment: As I said, I do not know what the rds files contain...

Comment: No worries! Thanks a lot for the help!